# Java ThreadPoolExexecutor using streams and Callables

Tags: java, java-stream, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I have a class which implements `Callable`, and it has a method which overrides `call` and returns a `Long`.

I create a `List` of `Callable<Long>` as

```
List<Callable<Long>> callables = new ArrayList<>();
for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    callables.add(new DataProcessor(fileEntry));
```

I have

```
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

and I call

```
threadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(callables)
    .stream()
    .map(future -> {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toLong(/* what goes here? */));
```

What I want to do is sum all the return values from `future.get()`.

Also, since I am calling the invokeAll, do I still need to do a shutdown on the Executor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Stream.mapToLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) to map the `future.get` as `LongStream` and then find the [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum()) of the stream as:

```
long sum = threadPoolExecutor.invokeAll(callables)
            .stream()
            .mapToLong(future -> {
                try {
                    return future.get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }) // LongStream
            .sum(); // sum of the stream
```

***Note***: This simplifies stream API call chains using `Collectors.summingLong`. It allows avoiding the creation of redundant temporary objects when traversing a collection.

***Aside***: You can also `collect` your `Callable`s as :

```
List<Callable<Long>> callables = fileList.stream()
                                         .map(fileEntry -> new DataProcessor(fileEntry))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> since I am calling the invokeAll, do I still need to do a shutdown on
>   the Executor?

Yes, you would have to shut down the `ExecutorService`. You can also confirm the status of the same using [`isShutDown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#isShutdown()) API as :

```
System.out.println(threadPoolExecutor.isShutdown()); // would return false
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I would like to time how long it takes from invokeall until all the threads are done.  But if I collect the end time after executor shutdown. It doesn’t wait for all the threads to complete.

Comment: @Mark Did you mean to benchmark the time taken for all callables to compute? Not able to get what exactly did you mean by collect the end time.

Comment: Yes.  Exactly.  That’s what I meant

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `Collectors.summingLong`:

```
.collect(Collectors.summingLong(r -> r));
```

Where `r -> r` is just a `ToLongFunction` that makes a `long` out of each `Long` returned by your `Callable`s.

> Also, since I am calling the invokeAll, do I still need to do a shutdown on the Executor?

`ExecutorService.invokeAll` doesn't document an automatic shutdown. So you'll need to shut it down yourself